# Какой MediaType надо указать что-бы боаузер понял что надо скачивать файл?

Tags: java, http

У меня контроллер отдает `xml` файл который должен скачиваться, а не открываться в браузере. Какой `MediaType` надо указать что-бы браузер понял что не надо открывать его в окне? Так что бы без костылей. Спасибо.

```
resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", format("attachment; filename=%s", filename));
```

Comment: Это зависит не от заголовка `Content-Type`, а от `Content-Disposition`.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev да точно. Спасибо. А какой Content-Disposition явно скажет что файл должен скачиваться